# Make an array of specific field of object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to make an array of a specific field of object from an array of objects. Here is what I did. How it can be more efficient?

```
    var array_obectj = [
        {   a: 'somestring1',
            b: 42,
            c: false},
        {
            a: 'somestring2',
            b: 42,
            c: false
        }];

    var arrayP = [];

    for (var i in array_obectj){
        arrayP.push(array_obectj[i].a)
    }
```

Comment: `const arrayP = array_obectj.map(({ a }) => a);` Also try to use proper spelling in programming

Answer (score 7):

You can use `map()`

```js
var array_obectj = [{
    a: 'somestring1',
    b: 42,
    c: false
  },
  {
    a: 'somestring2',
    b: 42,
    c: false
  }
];

var arrayP = array_obectj.map(o => o.a);

console.log(arrayP);
```

Doc: [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object destructuring` so that you can get the property value directly by specifying the property as `{a}`.

```js
var array_obectj = [
  {   a: 'somestring1',
      b: 42,
      c: false},
  {
      a: 'somestring2',
      b: 42,
      c: false
  }];

var arrayP =  array_obectj.map(({a}) => a);
console.log(arrayP);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How it can be more efficient?

First, we need to make it correct; `for-in` isn't how you [loop through arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476). The equivalent would be a simple `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_object.length; ++i) {
    arrayP.push(array_obectj[i].a)
}
```

Then, what you have is already quite efficient. JavaScript engines optimize `Array#push` really well.

Other options:

- Assign to the next index in the loop:

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < array_object.length; ++i) {
      arrayP[i] = array_obectj[i].a;
  }
  ```

  Some JavaScript engines will optimize that better than `push`, but some do `push` better.
- Use `map`:

  ```
  arrayP = array_object.map(e => e.a);
  ```

  ...but note that `map` has to make calls back to your callback function. Still, browsers optimize that well, too.

---

**However**, "how can it be more efficient" is usually not the question you want to ask. "How can it be clearer?" "How can I ensure the code is easy to read?" "How can I make this easily maintainable?" are all better questions to ask. Answering those, I'd say `map` is the clearest. It's a specific idiom for exactly this operation.